# How to integrate Face ID on capacitor 3 and Ionic 6 app

Tags: capacitor, ionic6

Im trying to integrate FaceID on my Ionic 6 + Capacitor 3-4 app but the only documentation I found is Ionic enterprise plug-in which costs a fortune.

Is there a modern, open source solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-native-biometric). Already used it in one of my projects. By default it uses the fingerprint but the user have an option to choose from fingerprint or faceID.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I wonder if you know a similar plug-in to implement Apple Pay?

Comment: Hi @VladimirLopezSalvador you can check this https://stripe.capacitorjs.jp/docs/google-pay. Note that this is under Stripe.